# About log4j 2.0 configuration

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2 in a project for logging. My conf file named as log4j2.xml is directly under java project and I have necessary jars in classpath. 
When I test if logging works correctly with the conf file below, I see just error messages although I expect to see info messages too. Do anybody know what is the problem here?

log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <properties>
        <property name="servicename">m2mp_checker</property>
        <property name="patternTime">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n</property>
        <property name="patternNoTime">%-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n</property>
    </properties>
    <appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patternTime}"/>
        </Console>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

java code:

```
package test;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

import com.jcraft.jsch.*;

/**
 * @author : T12888
 */
public class Tester {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Tester.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String username = "aa";
        String host = "aa";
        String pass = "aa";
        String khfile = "/home/testuser/.ssh/known_hosts";
        String identityfile = "/home/testuser/.ssh/id_rsa";

        JSch jsch = null;
        Session session = null;
        Channel channel = null;
        ChannelSftp c = null;

        try {

            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(pass);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();

            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            c = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            logger.info("info");
            String fsrc = "abc.xml", fdest = "abc.xml";
            c.put(fsrc, fdest);
            c.get(fdest, "/tmp/testfile.bin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            c.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
11:27:45.873 [main] ERROR test.Tester - error
```

Comment: upload your source code,where u calling logger.info("info");

Comment: ok I did. By the way when I debug I see logger.info line is working however since logger.isInfoEnabled() returns false no log writtent for this.

Comment: ok, are u writing messages in log file?

Comment: "patternTime" where r u setting pattern time?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to set `${patternTime}`

Set it like this: `System.setProperty("patternTime", Your_PatternTime);`

Comment: In the properties part in log4j2.xml I already defined patterntime with <property name="patternTime">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %-5.5p | %-10.10t | %-20.20C:%-5.5L | %msg%n</property>.

Comment: then what this line do?
<Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patternTime}"/>
        </Console>

Answer (score 0):

Finally its solved. The problem was log4j was not loading my configuration file(log4j2.xml) and using default configuration which sets logger to error level I guess. Thank you for responses.